# Android Views Size computation equivalent to ios view size

Tags: android

I have an app, ready for ios.
But i am using constant sizes in positioning of view. for example : the padding of imageview is 10pixels from left.

In android i am using 10dp..is it correct??
What will be the equivalent way and perfect way to do this in android, so that my android app will target various sized android devices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the different devices running Android, creating a layout on android is quite different to the way you do it on iOS (on the other hand, an Android app wouldn't have problems if you run it on a slightly higher screen like iPhone4 -> iPhone 5). You'll have quite some stuff to learn in order to understand Android's ways of layout. Here are some starting points for you:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/

Answer (score 0):

In android it is difficult to use definite sizes like `10dp` because of fragmentation. Small sizes that are used as padding are unlikely to matter very much, but if your entire layout is contingent on given pixel distances you may have to change some things.

Due to fragmentation in android developers tend to use layouts that are more contingent in each view being put in a position relative to another view.

However using sizes like this should not matter that much for a few reasons. One, as long as you test your views on a range of different screen sizes you should be fine

And two, if you need to make new layouts for tablets sized devices you can do that using Google's multi apk functionality - http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

To set the sizes in your layout by using density you should look here - [Defining layout.xml files based on screen density (v.2.3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205572/defining-layout-xml-files-based-on-screen-density-v-2-3-3)

In android this is a complicated process, which will involve you making many copies of each layout.

Comment: Thanks jcw.. But there is some thing called as display density. can u help me to size views depending on the density

Comment: I added some advice on that, the link has a full answer

Comment: Got That. thanks.. i am hoping to avoid this... but i guess i have to do this way only!!!!!

Comment: Yes , unfortunately that is one of the drawbacks of android